# Problem with Pandas query function not evaluating/subsetting correctly

Tags: python, pandas

Why does `df.query("ColumnB > '6'")` evaluate to the second row of the dataframe only? Expected answer was second to fifth row because those are rows where the values in Column B are greater than 6.

---

[image]

Comment: Ideally for that comparison to work, `ColumnB` should be of type `int` or `float`. So you might want to remove quotes from `6`. Should be: `df.query("ColumnB > 6")`

Comment: Probably because it's doing string comparison? You quoted 6

Comment: You can also try doing `df[df['ColumnB'] > 6]`. Check if this gets you the right result.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. However when I unquote 6, I get a type error. 

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

As a side note, although I'm aware this can be done through boolean indexing, I am currently exploring ways how to filter data with the query function specifically. Any ideas how to make it evaluate correctly?

Comment: Do this:  `df['ColumnB'] = df['ColumnB'].astype(int)` and then run `df.query("ColumnB > 6")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `ColumnB` into `int`:

```
df['ColumnB'] = df['ColumnB'].astype(int)
df.query("ColumnB > 6")
```